# Не могу подключить библиотеку в проект в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, library, build-error, implementation

Мне нужно подключить библиотеку [blurkit](https://github.com/CameraKit/blurkit-android). Я взял implementation из github, но при перестройке проекта мне выдает, что не может найти эту библиотеку.
[image]

Я уже добавлял другие библиотеки в свой проект, которые работают. Но с некоторыми, как например с этой, возникают проблемы такого плана.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "health.mental.melissa"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22'
    implementation 'com.github.santalu:maskara:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.alterac.blurkit:blurkit:1.1.0'

}
```

**build.gradle('name')**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: как вариант можно приложить build.gradle файл для начала

Comment: @Andrew приложил

Comment: выкладывайте текст текстом, а не картинкой. Это помогает поисковикам правильно индексировать страницы

Comment: я взял вашу библиотеку, подключил так - `implementation 'io.alterac.blurkit:blurkit:1.1.0'` и никаких ошибок нет, попробуйте почистить проект или кеш очистить вообще, так же как вариант попробуйте обновить градл версию плагина, до самой свежей 7.0.2